# node-canvas image manipulation

Tags: javascript, canvas, node.js, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to resize and crop an image in node.js

I've been using graphicsmagick:

code is as follows:

```
gm(path)
.resize(width, height)
.crop(50, 50, left, top)
.write(path, function(err){})
```

It's very simple. I have no idea how to use canvas, what's the equivalent in canvas?

Thanks.

Comment: why MUST you use node-canvas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For some reason, this signature is never used in examples:

```
context.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
```

- img = the image element
- sx = source x
- sy = source y
- sw = source width
- sh = source height
- dx = destination x
- dy = destination y
- dw = destination width
- dh = destination height

Crop using sx, sy, sw, sh

Resize using dw, dh

Comment: Nice tip. Mozilla docs were helpful too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: I am using node canvas api, when i try to resize it crops the image. For example i have image of 150x150 and i want it 50x50. I try
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,150,150,0,0,50,50);

Comment: while resize in greaater then actual size it works.
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,150,150,0,0,300,300);